# How do you save layers as separate files in the paint tool SAI?

Tags: layers, animation, sai

I am using SAI as an animation tool and therefore I will need to save the layers as separate images so that I can use a different animation program to put them together. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Welcome to GD.SE!  Please what is "SAI"? Suppose not all readers here know this abreviation ...

Comment: Uhm, it's not an acronym or an abbreviation, just another way to say 'Paint Tool SAI' without having to say the whole entire thing. Like a nickname, I guess you could say.

Comment: SAI is an application. I, for one, have never heard of it. But then it doesn't appear to be an English native application.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can! by saving the SAI as .psd file and from Photoshop using Script -> Export Layer to files option for exporting all your layer into separate images.

Answer (score 0):

You can turn off your other layers so only one image frame is showing and export it as a .jpg or .png and repeat for the rest of your frames.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an accurate (rough or otherwise) animation, I would suggest to draw the first (frame), and turn the line work to a red, or a strong, semi-dark color. Lower the opacity.

Make another layer, then draw your next frame. Turn the line work into a lighter contrast color that pairs with the last; repeat the process, turning every other frame, say, (red, green, red, green, etc.)

To get the frames into another program, it is very tedious, the way I do it. 
Save every layer as it's own separate preferred image file (.png, .jpg, etc.), and open each into your preferred animation software. Select each frame, and copy each frame onto one alpha layer.

I recommend you turn them back to black (or your original color of choice,) because most animation softwares do the onion skin affect for you.